# pandas dataframe join-like operation

Tags: python, join, pandas, dataframe

I have a pd.Dataframe that contains the following:

```
student_id,course_id,mark
```

another dataframe contains:

```
date,student_id,course_id
```

I want to perform a "join" on both of the data in a such way that my resulting dataframe would contain:

```
date,student_id,course_id,mark
```

but I also do want it to be joined based on the double key (student_id,course_id) which is going to be unique in my dataframe.

How can I perform this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the documentation for [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)?

Answer (score 1):

sorry my bad, the answer was in the doc

result = pd.merge(left, right, how='left', on=['key1', 'key2'])